# New Line Happening When I Haven't Coded that in C

Tags: c, printf, newline, fgets

I'm just trying to surround a name by a space and a star.

eg.

```
* John *
```

but the output I get is:

```
* John
 *
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h> 

char name[30];

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 

    printf ("Please enter your name: ");
    fgets ( name , 30 , stdin );

    printf ("* %s *", name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` will consume the `\n` from the input and put it into the string.

Comment: Add `#include <string.h>` and after your `fgets()` call, add `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;` to trim the trailing `'\n'` from the end of `name` by overwriting the `'\n'` with the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` (or just plain `0`)..

Comment: Thanks, this worked, also I found that when you just type `gets(name);` it also works without having to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string.

You should remove it. You can do it the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//…

fgets ( name , 30 , stdin )
name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

fgets() is also getting the newline character you input in with enter. You just have to remove that \n. Just do `name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0'`.

Comment: oops, I just typed in the wrong thing

Comment: You can always fix it

Comment: Also better to `size_t len = strlen(name);` then test that `len` is greater than `0` and that the character at the end is the `'\n'` character, e.g. `if [len && name[len-1] == '\n'] name[--len] = 0;` Otherwise if the line is the *empty-string* (no `'\n'`) you attempt to set `name[-1] = 0;` and that is bad...

Comment: @anastaciu, the person who commented before that deleted their comment after I fixed it

Comment: Ok, it's just a general advice, if it's like you want it to be, it's fine.

Comment: @Warpstar22 - you are free to draw from my comment to include that information in your answer if you like. If you do, drop a comment to me and I can come back and erase my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `fgets` is also reading in the newline character when the user hits the enter key. You can try to use `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

Comment: Ooof..... (no dings), but generally that isn't what you think of as an improvement. You have 2 problems. (1) you fail to include the *field-width* modifier limiting the number of characters that can be read by `scanf` to `29` (no better than `gets()` without it), and (2) you now leave the `'\n'` in `stdin` unread. If the next call is a `fgets()` as well and you haven't extracted the `'\n'` from `stdin`, the next `fgets()` fails. Generally `fgets()` and trimming the `'\n'` is preferred over `scanf` for those reasons.